# Java String.format failed to format Date and Integer altogether

Tags: java, exception, string.format

I am trying to format date with Integer but they both work separately fine but when I put them together it throws following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.util.Date
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.format(Unknown Source)
    at Test.main(Test.java:10)
```

Code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String format = "http://az.website.com/api/calendar/date/%1$tY-%1$tm-%1$te/user_id/%d";

        Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        System.out.println(String.format(format, date, 23));
    }

}
```

If I remove date format `%1$tY-%1$tm-%1$te` then it starts working fine but together it throws `IlelgalFormatConversionExpception`.

What's wrong with this code ?

**Update**

Code that runs but produces wrong out put.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String format = "http://az.website.com/api/calendar/date/%1$tY-%1$tm-%1$te/user_id/%2$%d";

        Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        System.out.println(String.format(format, date) + 23);

    }

}
```

Output: http://az.website.com/api/calendar/date/2014-01-30/user_id/%d23

Code that produce erros:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String format = "http://az.website.com/api/calendar/date/%1$tY-%1$tm-%1$te/user_id/%2$d";

        Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        System.out.println(String.format(format, date) + 23);

    }

}
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '2$d'
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.format(Unknown Source)
    at Test.main(Test.java:10)
```

Using Java 1.6 Android 4.3 also tried on

```
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

**Update**
@Sotirios Delimanolis is really a life saver. I was calling the method wrongly.
Wrong --> System.out.println(String.format(format, date) + 23);

Right --> System.out.println(String.format(format, date, 23));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a reference to the second argument in the argument list with `2$`

```
String format = "http://az.website.com/api/calendar/date/%1$tY-%1$tm-%1$te/user_id/%2$d";
```

`String.format(...)` internally uses a [`Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) whose javadoc states

> The argument index is a decimal integer indicating the position of the
>   argument in the argument list. The first argument is referenced by
>   "1$", the second by "2$", etc.

Comment: There was an error it will not be $d rather %d. I have corrected it and marked as accepted.

Comment: @AZ_ Euh, it should be `%2$d`. Try it. The `%` to mark as something to replace, the `2$` as a marker for the second argument in the argument list, and `d` for a decimal format, as the documentation says.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '2$d'
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.String.format(Unknown Source)
 at Test.main(Test.java:10)

Comment: @AZ_ Are you missing the leading `%`?

Comment: I have tried it dear and after confirming I made the change. No offense It really not working.

Comment: I just copy pasted your code. but it throws me the exception dear

Comment: @AZ_ What Java version are you on? This works fine for me on Java 7. And the documentation supports it.

Comment: This works fine String format = "http://az.website.com/api/calendar/date/%1$tY-%1$tm-%1$te/user_id/%2%d";

Comment: @AZ_ The [javadoc for 1.6 `Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) says the same thing.

Comment: @AZ_ I don't know what to follow in your link. Your file isn't saved.

Comment: Eclipse never run a file if its not saved. I tried to save it again and run again but same result I am using %2%d and it's working fine dear.

Comment: @AZ_ That depends on configuration. What value is it generating after the formatting?

Comment: Exception: Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '2$d'
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.String.format(Unknown Source)
 at Test.main(Test.java:10)

Comment: @AZ_ Also, you are obviously using `1$` in the format, so why wouldn't  `2$` work?

Comment: with %2%d it generates http://az.website.com/api/calendar/date/2014-01-30/user_id/%d23

Comment: @AZ_ That seems wrong to me. Can you edit your question and add the actual code that you are running that works and the one that fails?

Comment: @AZ_ Your last path segment in that code is `%2$%d`. It should instead be `%2$d`. If you are saying that is not working, I have no idea...It works for me.

Comment: @AZ_ Oh, you're calling `format` incorrectly for this case. It should be `String.format(format, date, 23)`.

Comment: oh God, You are really a hero :-) Thanks you very much. It's really a very stupid mistake. sorry for you wasting your time brother.

Comment: @AZ_ No worries, glad we figured it out. Good luck!